# Ubuntu 16.04 problems

Tags: xubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop but I am getting the error in the following image. Please help. The image of problem is https://photos.app.goo.gl/JoCcWMfZNAdvJa749

Comment: You really need to transcribe the text from the image.

Comment: What model is your laptop? At what point does this error message start?